# Tabulator callEditCancelled Callback: How to the Determine Key Code?

Tags: tabulator

I am attempting to capture the key code which triggered a `cellEditCancelled` callback within `Tabulator` as follows:

```
var table = new Tabulator(divId, {
    cellEditCancelled: function (cell) {
        //cell - cell component
        var col = cell.getField();
        var mycode= event.which || event.keyCode;  //'event' is undefined
        alert("cellEditCancelled called\ncolumn: " + col + "\nkeyCode: " + mycode);
    },
    columns: [
        { title: "Project ID", field: "Projectid", widthGrow: 1, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", editor: "autocomplete", editorParams: { showListOnEmpty: true, allowEmpty: false, values: window.projectIdList } },
        { title: "Cust Job", field: "CustomerJobId", widthGrow: 1.25, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", editor: "autocomplete", editorParams: { showListOnEmpty: true, allowEmpty: false, values: window.customerJobIdList } },
        { title: "Project Desc", field: "ProjectDesc", widthGrow: 1.5, responsive: 0, hozAlign: "center", editor: "autocomplete", editorParams: { showListOnEmpty: true, allowEmpty: false, values: window.projDescList } },
    ]
});
```

Unlike other callbacks within `Tabulator` the `callEditCancelled` callback apparently does not expose an `event` object. (For example, the `cellClick` callback exposes an event object in its associated function signature.)

I need to differentiate between `keyCode` values in order to determine how to handle the `callEditCancelled` event.  For example, clicking the `Tab` key would be handled differently than clicking the `Esc` key.

It's gotta be something simple.  What am I missing?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event object isn't passed into this function because an ***cancel edit*** event isn't triggered by a key press, it could be triggered by any number of things:

- Loss of focus
- Keypress
- Mouse event
- Scroll
- Table resize
- Row update
- the ***cancelEdit*** function being called on the cell component or table

If you are just talking about key events then it is not actually up to the table when to trigger a cancel event, these are actually handled individually by each editor, each editor has a series of bindings that listen for loss of focus or certain key events and can then choose to either do nothing, trigger a ***success*** or a ***cancel*** function.

Further details on this can be found in the [Editor Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/edit#edit-custom)

For these reasons there is no event object passed into the ***callEditCancelled*** callback. by the time this function has been called the edit has been cancelled and there is nothing that can be done to stop that.

If you are specifically looking to track the key events then you could look at adding a listener to the document that listens for the last keypress/mouse event and stores that event object in a globally accessible variable.  You could then check that variable in the ***callEditCancelled*** callback to see what the last event was.

Comment: Oli, as always, thank you for you response.  I will attempt to add a listener to the document.  Thanks again.